# error [ModuleException] Doctrine2: Module can't be accessed

Tags: codeception

I am having trouble to follow the doc in https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Doctrine2. This the error 
`[ModuleException] Doctrine2: Module can't be accessed`

I want to access `$entityManger` in the unit test. The doctrine `bootstrap.php` have a `createEntityManager` function that returns `entityManager`.

```
#codeception.yml
suites:
    unit:
        path: .
        actor: UnitTester
        modules:
            enabled:
                # add more modules here
                - Asserts
settings:
    bootstrap: ../config/bootstrap.php
    shuffle: true
    lint: true
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    support: tests/_support
    data: tests
```

```
# unit.suite.yml
actor: UnitTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - Doctrine2:
      connection_callback: ['createEntityManager']
      cleanup: true # All doctrine queries will be wrapped in a transaction, which will be rolled back at the end of each test
    - \Helper\Unit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have unit suite configured in codeception.yml file, so your unit.suite.yml is ignored.

Remove this section from codeception.yml or remove unit.suite.yml and update codeception.yml

```
suites:
    unit:
        path: .
        actor: UnitTester
        modules:
            enabled:
                # add more modules here
                - Asserts
```